# How to add an "extended help" option to argparse

Tags: python-3.x, workflow, argparse

I have a program that calls a function with **dozens** of optional parameters, all of which can be customized via **key-value pairs** on the command line.

It every so often happens that I forget the exact name of one of those optional arguments, so I try to add an "extended help" command line argument to my ArgumentParser that **prints the docstring** of the function (where all these optional arguments are explained in sufficient detail).

**My problem is:** The program also has required arguments, so a call like `my_prog.py --extended_help` will result in an error stating "the following arguments are required...".

One solution of course would be to simply add all the optional arguments of my function to ArgumentParser, but that would **duplicate** the information in the source file (once in the ArgumentParser, once in the function docstring).

Is there a way to somehow "override" the required attribute in case `--extended_help` is set?

`ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group` consisting of `--extended_help` and a group containing the other parameters might be a possibility. But the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group) of `argparse` states that this is an unintended functionality (that never completely worked) and will be removed from future versions.

Moving my required parameters in a `Subparser` might be an option but then I would need to always add a superfluous argument every time I use the program as intended.

Any further ideas?

Comment: The regular `--help` uses an `Action` class that prints its information and exits.  Your extendedhelp could be modeled on that.

Comment: Don't be distracted by the documentation about mutually-exclusive-groups.  Argument Groups are used in displaying the help; mutually exclusive groups are used in parsing; they don't do anything in the help (except in the usage).  And everything in a multually_exclusive_group has to be optional.

Comment: The simplest fix is to make everything flagged, and not required.  Provide reasonable defaults for things that the users might want to skip.  Then your '--extended-help' will just be another flagged argument that you can act on after parsing.

Comment: You could look at `sys.argv` directly.  If it includes a key word, such as '--extend_help' then call your own custom `help` code.  Otherwise, call the `parser.parse_args()` to handle that input in the normal way.

Comment: Thanks, @hpaulj, for the ideas. For my application I'll go with looking at sys.argv. Simple and effective and minimal effort.

Answer (score 0):

Just use another parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import sys


def main():
    parser_eh = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser_eh.add_argument('--extended-help',action='store_true')
    ehargs = parser_eh.parse_args()
    if ehargs.extended_help:
        print("Yada")
        sys.exit(0)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('something')

    args = parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```